# ReferenceError when using Android Emulator

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, stripe-payments, ionic4

I'm using stripe v3 with my ionic 4 app and angular. Recently i compiled app both on android and iOS. When im using

```
cordova ionic emulate ios
```

everything works great. When im use:

```
cordova ionic emulate android
```

app is building, but i got white screen after splashscreen. I implemented stripe in `index.html`:

```
<head>
<head>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<!-- rest of code... ->
```

Error from chrome console:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Stripe is not
>   defined
>       ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined at new PaymentsService

payments service:

```
Declare var Stripe;
```

Browser and iOS working. Android  in emulator - not.

What should i fix?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me.

I fixed my problem, to be honest - i dont know why its working, but:

1. Deleted android platform

```
ionic cordova platform remove android
```

2. Deleted www folder

```
rm -rf www/
```

3. Rebuilded android platform:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

4. Added "async" to my index.html

```
<!-- async added to script tag -->
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/" async></script>
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Adding that script tag is not enough for Ionic. You need to use proper dependency injection and there is a plugin for Stripe.

I suggest following their documentation to see how to get this working:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/stripe

and

https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-stripe

Here is a guide of integrating the plugin. However if you are working with v3, there might be differences. Not sure if the plugin supports that version yet

https://enappd.com/blog/ionic-4-stripe-payment-integration-with-firebase-for-apps-and-pwa/17/

Other than all the above, it's worth checking that your app allows files to be fetched from the stripe CDN.

```
<allow-navigation href="https://js.stripe.com" />
```

Try adding the above in your config xml

If you insist on doing it with the javascript library and not using the plugin, maybe the place where you declare Stripe is not right.

Try putting it in typings/cordova-typings.d.ts

Comment: Nope. I need to create stripe elements which is available on v3 version. On iOS everything working. In this plugins there's no API for: elements(). I can't use createCardToken due to new regulations. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Comment: Well the rtoot of the issue is what I describe. Ionic v4 uses typescript and replies heavily on dependency injection. Just declaring a script tag is not going to work. You need to create a module and inject that module into your service or wherever it is required

Comment: Check the section I added above regarding allow-navigation. Maybe that is your issue.

Comment: Thank you fellows. Im gonna publish anserwe within minutes.